# How to transfer data and replica information from a file geodatabase to ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, replication

I've got an arcgis 10.1 file geodatabase that contains a number of featureclasses and a number of one-way child replicas.

Is there any tool that I can use to transfer the data and replica information verbatim into an ArcSDE geodatabase?  I'm giving the replica file geodatabase to an external person and I want him to easily be able to move the data and replica information to an ArcSDE database which he will then version and publish as a geodata service that I'll replicate to.

The Extract Data Wizard in the distributed data toolbar does half the job by transferring the featureclasses verbatim (including GlobalIDs).  But replica information does not appear to be transferred.

Create Replica doesn't appear to help in this situation.

Comment: Is it an option to copy all the feature classes you want to the new SDE server first and then create a new series of replicas using the "register existing data only" option? Replicas use versioning states behind the scenes so it might be hard to copy this information from one format to another.

Comment: @Dowlers thanks for the 'register existing data only option' suggestion.  Although it didn't help me in this case, that suggestion did help me understand replicas a little more.  It turns out that I needed to replicate to an XML document and then use Import XML Workspace Document at the other end.  I'll post the link below.  Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand replicas a little better now and it turns out that I needed to replicate to an XML document when using the Create Replica Wizard in ArcMAP.  I then send the XML Document to the person at the other end and they can use the Import -> XML Workspace Document within ArcCatalog to import both the data and replica information into their ArcSDE geodatabase.
The geodatabase is published as a geodata service on the Internet and I can then synchronise the replicas.

This [document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#//00rq0000003n000000) on ESRI's arcgis.com site describes the process in more detail.